# How to center Bootstrap Vue pagination under table?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a Bootstrap Vue table with a pagination component underneath it.  I've currently got it in a separate row in a single column but whilst it looks "fairly" centred, it's actually not centred in the column and there is uneven padding/margin on the right side. Looking like it's from the  tag (per image).

[image]

How can I horizontally centre the pagination pls?

```
</b-table>

<b-row align-h="center" align-content="center">
  <b-col cols="3">

    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="totalRows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
      
    ></b-pagination>

  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Comment: try adding `justify-content: center;` to your `.pagination` class

Comment: That worked!  Thank you - can you put it as an answer and I will mark as correct for you! Cheers :-)

Comment: Done ! thanks Johnny John Boy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cols="auto"` instead of `cols="3"`, that way the column will automatically size itself after the content, instead a specific width as you have now.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#variable-width-content

```html
<b-row align-h="center" align-content="center">
  <b-col cols="auto">
    <b-pagination></b-pagination>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

You could also use Bootstraps [Flex Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/)

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <b-pagination></b-pagination>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `justify-content: center;` to your `.pagination` class